# UIImageView disappears when enabling "ClipToBounds"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an `UIImageView` element that I added via Interface Builder (`XIB` file).

I create an `IBOutlet` to this imageView and on `awakeFromNib()` method I add those 2 lines (for creating a circular imageView):

```
self.myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.myImageView.frame.size.width / 2
self.myImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

The constraints to this `UIImageView` (via `Interface Builder`, `NameLabel` is a `UIlabel` with frame of: `x: 27, y: 170, width: 319, height: 25`) are:

- Width = 77
- Top space to `SuperView` = 88
- Bottom space to `NameLabel` = 5
- Align center X = `NameLabel`

When I run the app I can't see the imageView - it just disappears!

Note: (I think it happened every time a constraint sets its height).

Note 2: When I remove `self.myImageView.clipsToBounds = true` line or `self.myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.myImageView.frame.size.width / 2` line it works!

Any idea how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: How you added imageview ..?

Comment: @vaibhav As I wrote above, using `Interface Builder` (`XIB` file)

Comment: Okay, show more code and screenshots.

Comment: @vaibhav What code? the 2 lines that added are the only relevant code, it's probably a problem between these lines and the constraints

Comment: I don't think these two lines only responsible for this undefined behaviour, something more is too it may be constraints :)

Comment: @vaibhav So do you have any idea what could it be?